# Schengen 90/180 rule question

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a question regarding my specific case and how long I may stay in Europe on my American passport. I am a student and am currently finish a term in London. During the term, I have spent a total of 17 days in the Schengen area (not sure if it's relevant to figuring out the calculation, but the first day I entered was 11th February). On 24th May, I will be entering again and staying until 11th July (49 days). From there I will be traveling to Ireland for about a week, but return to the Schengen area from 19th-28th July (10 days). I will then be spending another week in England. These dates are set in stone due to a variety of reasons that have to do with meeting friends and family in various places. I will be beginning another term in Spain on 30th August, but will of course be able to enter Spain at that time with the visa that I will have obtained.

The question is this: how much of the period from 4th-30th August will I legally be allowed to spend inside the Schengen area? Again, between 11th February and 27th July I will have spent a total of 76 days there. Any help you can give would be extremely helpful. To be clear, I've done a lot of reading here and on other sites to try to find my answer without posing a question myself, but most other Schengen questions seem to be from people who have had to obtain Schengen visas prior to travel, and I'm not sure whether this alters things. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious, if you are a student attending university, why are you not on a long term student visa?

Comment: @CGCampbell it's a UK university apparently so that visa would not help

Comment: @Relaxed OK, I completely missed "finish a term in **London**" thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering without a visa (if your citizenship allows it) or obtaining a Schengen visa in advance (if you have to) does not make any difference with respect to the 90/180 maximum stay rule so so all the info you found about visa-holders fully applies to visa-exempt visitors like yourself as well.

You can check [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) for a full explanation. Assuming the first stay was from the 11th to the 27th of February, [the calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) suggests you can stay for up to 29 days if you enter on the 30th of July 2015. So you do have to spend a couple of days elsewhere before August 30 (but do check by yourself with the exact dates of your various trips).

Comment: I removed my answer. I didn't realize that the window was sliding. This is the correct answer.